# Solving equation

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-curves

Assume that $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ are known value integers , and $P$, $Q$, $R$ and $G$ are known value points on an elliptic curve with these equations:
$$a = by+x, \\
c=\frac{1}{y}d +z , \\
P= x\frac{1}{y}Q + \frac{1}{y}R + zG$$

Can we find the values of $x$, $y$ and $z$ or not?

Note: $x$, $y$, $z$ are integer numbers such that their values are unknown for us.